# Como atualizar o recyclerView após atualizar dados via dialog

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Meu aplicativo funciona mais ou menos assim.

Dentro de um fragmento tenho um RecyclerView composto de cardviews, alimentadas por um banco de dados.

Em cada card, tem um botão editar (imageView) que abre um dialogo (alertDialog) com um form. de edição. Tá tudo funcionando, menos a atualização do reclyclerview.

Abaixo o adaptador do recyclerview

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast; 

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<RunData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private RunDbHelper runDbHelper; // db model helper class 

RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<RunData> dataList1) {

    this.context = context;
    this.dataList = dataList1;
    this.runDbHelper = RunDbHelper.getInstance(this.context);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View inflateView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_row, parent, false);
    return new RecyclerViewHolder(inflateView);
}

// Parse data from dataList to holder and setup all Views
// Here is part of the magic
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.runID.setText(dataList.get(position).run_id);
    holder.collectAddress.setText(dataList.get(position).collect_address);
    holder.collectPerson.setText(dataList.get(position).collect_person);
    holder.runParcel.setText(dataList.get(position).run_parcel);
    holder.deliveryAddress.setText(dataList.get(position).delivery_address);
    holder.deliveryPerson.setText(dataList.get(position).delivery_person);        

    holder.ivEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RunData runData = new RunData(); // helper class to deal with one data row mirrors model
            runData.collect_address = holder.collectAddress.getText().toString();
            runData.collect_person = holder.collectPerson.getText().toString();
            runData.delivery_address = holder.deliveryAddress.getText().toString();
            runData.delivery_person = holder.deliveryPerson.getText().toString();
            runData.run_id = holder.runID.getText().toString();
            dialogEditRun(runData);
        }

    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

public void dialogEditRun(RunData runData) {

    // Get the Activity for layout inflater as this dialog runs inside a fragment
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final View inflaterView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_edit_run, null);
    // Data entry field objects
    final EditText runParcelEditText = (EditText) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.editRunParcel);
    final AutoCompleteTextView collectAddressACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.actvEditCollectAddress);
    final EditText collectPersonEditText = (EditText) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.editCollectPerson);
    final AutoCompleteTextView deliveryAddressACTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.actvEditDeliveryAddress);
    final EditText deliveryPersonEditText = (EditText) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.editDeliveryPerson);
    final String mRunID;
    // get values from database and set edit values
    runParcelEditText.setText(runData.run_parcel);
    collectAddressACTV.setText(runData.collect_address);
    deliveryAddressACTV.setText(runData.delivery_address);
    collectPersonEditText.setText(runData.collect_person);
    deliveryPersonEditText.setText(runData.delivery_person);
    mRunID = runData.run_id;

    // Dialog Builder
    AlertDialog.Builder editRunDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    editRunDialog.setTitle(R.string.dialog_update_run_title)
        .setView(inflaterView);

    editRunDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_positive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            RunData runData = new RunData();
            runData.run_parcel = getStringOrEmpty(runParcelEditText);
            runData.collect_address = getStringOrEmpty(collectAddressACTV);
            runData.delivery_address = getStringOrEmpty(deliveryAddressACTV);
            runData.collect_person = getStringOrEmpty(collectPersonEditText);
            runData.delivery_person = getStringOrEmpty(deliveryPersonEditText);
            runData.run_id = mRunID;



            if (!(runData.collect_address.isEmpty() && runData.delivery_address.isEmpty())){
                // try to update, if success update recycler.
                if (runDbHelper.updateRun(runData, context)){ 
                // when true, update successfull
                // now, update recyclerview

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Record not updated. try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.dialog_insert_run_toast_nowhere, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    editRunDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_negative, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    editRunDialog.create();
    editRunDialog.show();

}

private String getStringOrEmpty(EditText editText) {
    String mString = editText.getText().toString();
    mString = (mString.isEmpty() ? "" : mString);
    return mString;
}

class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView runID, collectPerson, collectAddress, deliveryPerson, deliveryAddress, runParcel;
    ImageView ivEdit;


    RecyclerViewHolder(View rowView) {
        super(rowView);
        runID = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.runId);
        collectAddress = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.collectAddress);
        collectPerson = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.collectPerson);
        runParcel = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.runParcel);
        deliveryAddress = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.deliveryAddress);
        deliveryPerson = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.deliveryPerson);
        ivEdit = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivEdit);
    }
}

}
```

E agora? Quem poderá nos salvar???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quiser inserir ou remover itens dentro do *adapter*, você precisará informa-lo explicitamente que houve uma mudança. Isso é um pouco diferente do `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Basta criar dois métodos de inserção e remoção.

```
public void add(RunData item, int position) {
    items.add(position, item);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void remove(RunData item) {
    int position = items.indexOf(item);
    items.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Usando desta forma, será mais eficiente do que usar o `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` para verificação de mudança em toda sua lista.

Veja [na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) todos os métodos se tratando de `RecycleView.Adapter`.

Comment: Então, após atualizar o banco de dados, eu chamaria os métodos `remove()` e `add(), nesta ordem. Quanto ao remove, sem problemas, mas o add()... se entendi o código acima, como ele vai saber casar cada atributo de RunData, com a view correspondente? Considerando que ainda não estou usando data binding.

Comment: @ReneFreak Se você atualizar todo o banco, ou verificar em qualquer situação se há alguma mudança, você pode usar o `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. Agora por exemplo, você tem que adicionar um item que veio do banco, você deve usar o `add()` e da mesma forma o `remove()`.

Comment: enviei o comentario anterior antes de terminar e vc respondeu, enquanto eu o editava. Você é mesmo rapido no gatilho :-)

Comment: @ReneFreak observe que em algum momento você está adicionando e removendo itens na sua lista né?! Então tente fazer destas duas formas.

Comment: @ReneFreak como você disse que cada card tem um botão, você deve fazer a atualização somente do card. Isso é o legal do RecyclerView;

Comment: como no momento de atualizar o `cardView` eu já tenho a `position`, em vez de usar os métodos que você apresentou, usei os métodos `add()` e `remove()` do próprio adaptador. Mas o importante é que funcionou.

Comment: @ReneFreak legal. Se você quiser alterar a resposta e colocar alguma consideração importante, fique a vontade.

Answer (score 1):

Sua estrutura está confusa, seria interessante ter o adapter do RecyclerView pra complementar a resposta, mas a ideia é mais ou menos assim:

No seu adapter do RecyclerView você passa pelo construtor uma lista de elementos que compõe os cards, correto? Pois bem, pra atualizar o RecyclerView, tudo que você precisa é:

1. Pegar os dados que você está recolhendo no Dialog (pelo que eu vi vc ja faz isso)
2. Instanciar a classe que você usa como elemento da Lista com esses novos dados
3. Trocar na posição que foi clicada, o elemento antigo pelo novo
4. Avisar pro seu recyclerView que a lista mudou, através do `recyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged()`
5. Pronto!

Sem o seu código é dificil dar uma resposta mais precisa, mas esse é o passo a passo pra atualizar ele, levei em consideracao que voce faz o adapter como a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) sugere, mas caso esteja usando de um jeito diferente, edite sua resposta com o codigo do adapter que eu tento ser mais explicito.

Acho que ficou claro mas pelo sim pelo nao, boa sorte :P

Comment: atualizei a pergunta com o `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Avise se precisar de mais alguma informação. Agradeço o colaboração.